# How to set a background image to right center and still use a sprite?

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites, pseudo-element

Take a look at the following scenario:

[image]

Normally you would include the background image and set this to '*right center*'. Is there anyway however to have this but have the speech bubbles come from a sprite (contains multiple different images) where the element has an unknown width?

I was contemplating using the :after pseudo-element however I need to provide IE7 support.

I wanted to avoid extra HTML markup, thus I'm curious if a CSS only scenario exists.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on your sprites, I assume. If it contains all icons below each, read you have narrow but very high image, this shouldn't be a problem.
Other than that you might want to look at background image clipping, but I am not sure about IE7 on that one.

Comment: YouTube use common fix, just a 1pixel transparent gif that is stretched to fit the width of the image required and then apply the sprite image and position it using CSS. Personally I think @digitalclubb's might be better if you want to avoid adding extra markup.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a css pseudo element such as :before or :after.  Just size and position your pseudo element where you want it.  The content property is important, else it wont show up.

```
#divid:after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('sprite.png') -20px -15px no-repeat;
  content: ' ';
}
```

Comment: I was tempted to go down this route but :after isn't support in IE7 (which I have to support). Think I will just have to stick spans all over my markup :(

Comment: @digitalclubb You could also use Modernizr, they have support for CSS generated content.  Would take a bit of extra work but could save time down the road.